# Kubeflow Pipeline - How can I retrieve metrics regarding reusable components usage

Tags: github, metrics, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

everyone :)

I have Kubeflow running on EKS in our company as the official ML platform solution with hundred of Data Science user and different types of use cases.

My challenge is to measure the usage of our reusable components. These components are available in GitHub repository dedicated only for kubeflow reusable components that we build to increase productivity for our users.

Is it possible to gather metrics such as:

- total of users using our components
- total of pipelines
- total of runs
  etc...

thanks in advance for your help

Until now I didn't find anything useful

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.